# Select polygons containing particular attributes from points layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I have thousands of polygons (buffers) in a single layer and I have a points layer containing tree species. The tree species points shapefile has an attribute called `Tree_Type`. I need to select only the polygons that contain/intersect three particular species (as shown below). I've already tried multiple intersects to no avail.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use first the processing tools "join attributes by location" and next "Dissolve" to remove duplicates. Yours polygons need to have a unique id attribute.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the `new virtual layer` with the SQL script in the form window add 2 layers and run the SQL script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.geometry) geom FROM buffer a JOIN tree_pts b ON ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) WHERE b.tree_type='pear' OR b.tree_type='apple' OR b.tree_type='orange'
```

Save the result as a new file using `<Export>-<Save objects as... >`

Comment: I'm trying this in PostGIS now as QGIS was crashing. I've tried using `AND` to get each buffer that contains all tree_types but it doesn't work? I've also tried the above code with ```WHERE Tree_Type.Feature_Ty IN ('Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange')``` but this doesn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can assume that your polygon file has the wrong geometry...